# Invalid object name with #tem_table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I am trying to  execute a query to get highCpuUtilization queries  alert. It is displaying results, if I am  executing the query. When I want to send the results to my mail using dbmail, it is throwing error.

> (3 row(s) affected)
>
> (1 row(s) affected)
>
> (1 row(s) affected)
>
> Msg 22050, Level 16, State 1, Line 0 Error formatting query, probably
>   invalid parameters Msg 14661, Level 16, State 1, Procedure
>   sp_send_dbmail, Line 517 Query execution failed: Msg 208, Level 16,
>   State 1, Server FSQADBTRVS\FSQADBTR, Line 1 Invalid object name
>   '#PossibleCPUUtilizationQueries'.

Here is the Query, That I am trying to Run

```
DECLARE @ts_now bigint 
DECLARE @SQLVersion decimal (4,2) -- 9.00, 10.00
DECLARE @AvgCPUUtilization DECIMAL(10,2) 

SELECT @SQLVersion = LEFT(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('PRODUCTVERSION') AS VARCHAR), 4) -- find the SQL Server Version

-- sys.dm_os_sys_info works differently in SQL Server 2005 vs SQL Server 2008+
-- comment out SQL Server 2005 if SQL Server 2008+

-- SQL Server 2005
--IF @SQLVersion = 9.00
--BEGIN 
--  SELECT @ts_now = cpu_ticks / CONVERT(float, cpu_ticks_in_ms) FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info 
--END

-- SQL Server 2008+
IF @SQLVersion >= 10.00
BEGIN
    SELECT @ts_now = cpu_ticks/(cpu_ticks/ms_ticks) FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info
END 

-- load the CPU utilization in the past 3 minutes into the temp table, you can load them into a permanent table
SELECT TOP(3) SQLProcessUtilization AS [SQLServerProcessCPUUtilization]
,SystemIdle AS [SystemIdleProcess]
,100 - SystemIdle - SQLProcessUtilization AS [OtherProcessCPU Utilization]
,DATEADD(ms, -1 * (@ts_now - [timestamp]), GETDATE()) AS [EventTime] 
INTO #CPUUtilization
FROM ( 
      SELECT record.value('(./Record/@id)[1]', 'int') AS record_id, 
            record.value('(./Record/SchedulerMonitorEvent/SystemHealth/SystemIdle)[1]', 'int') 
            AS [SystemIdle], 
            record.value('(./Record/SchedulerMonitorEvent/SystemHealth/ProcessUtilization)[1]', 
            'int') 
            AS [SQLProcessUtilization], [timestamp] 
      FROM ( 
            SELECT [timestamp], CONVERT(xml, record) AS [record] 
            FROM sys.dm_os_ring_buffers 
            WHERE ring_buffer_type = N'RING_BUFFER_SCHEDULER_MONITOR' 
            AND record LIKE '%<SystemHealth>%') AS x 
      ) AS y 
ORDER BY record_id DESC


-- check if the average CPU utilization was over 90% in the past 2 minutes
SELECT @AvgCPUUtilization = AVG([SQLServerProcessCPUUtilization] + [OtherProcessCPU Utilization])
FROM #CPUUtilization
WHERE EventTime > DATEADD(MM, -2, GETDATE())

IF @AvgCPUUtilization >= 0
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP(10)
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),@AvgCPUUtilization) +'%' AS [AvgCPUUtilization]
        , GETDATE() [Date and Time]
        , r.cpu_time
        , r.total_elapsed_time
        , s.session_id
        , s.login_name
        , s.host_name
        , DB_NAME(r.database_id) AS DatabaseName
        , SUBSTRING (t.text,(r.statement_start_offset/2) + 1,
        ((CASE WHEN r.statement_end_offset = -1
            THEN LEN(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), t.text)) * 2
            ELSE r.statement_end_offset
        END - r.statement_start_offset)/2) + 1) AS [IndividualQuery]
        , SUBSTRING(text, 1, 200) AS [ParentQuery]
        , r.status
        , r.start_time
        , r.wait_type
        , s.program_name
    INTO #PossibleCPUUtilizationQueries     
    FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions s
    INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections c ON s.session_id = c.session_id
    INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_requests r ON c.connection_id = r.connection_id
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) t
    WHERE s.session_id > 50
        AND r.session_id != @@spid
    order by r.cpu_time desc

    -- query the temp table, you can also send an email report 

    SELECT * FROM #PossibleCPUUtilizationQueries

END

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
  @profile_name = 'Databasemail',
   @recipients = 'con-balususr@mail.com',
@query = 'SELECT * FROM #PossibleCPUUtilizationQueries',
   @subject = 'Work Order Count',
 @attach_query_result_as_file = 1 ;



-- drop the temp tables
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#CPUUtilization') IS NOT NULL
drop table #CPUUtilization

IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#PossibleCPUUtilizationQueries') IS NOT NULL
drop table #PossibleCPUUtilizationQueries
```

Comment: Dear Barry, Thankyou so much for immediate response. And that worked if CPu Utilization is >=0. If I am changing to any other number it is giving below error.Msg 22050, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
Error formatting query, probably invalid parameters
Msg 14661, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_send_dbmail, Line 517
Query execution failed: Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Server ULFSQADBTRVS\ULFSQADBTR, Line 1
Invalid object name '##PossibleCPUUtilizationQueries'. I m changing here IF @AvgCPUUtilization >= 85. Sorry I have no coding knowledge

Comment: No I got it now, if there are any queries taking that threshold then it is sending or else a failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail` will run in a different context and has no permissions to your declared temporary table.

Use a global temporary table instead (`##PossibleCPUUtilizationQueries`).

As Aaron quite rightly pointed out you could also just use a permanent table to store your data rather than use temporary tables.

See [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186986%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for more information regarding local and global temporary tables

> There are two types of temporary tables: local and global. Local
>   temporary tables are visible only to their creators during the same
>   connection to an instance of SQL Server as when the tables were first
>   created or referenced. Local temporary tables are deleted after the
>   user disconnects from the instance of SQL Server. Global temporary
>   tables are visible to any user and any connection after they are
>   created, and are deleted when all users that are referencing the table
>   disconnect from the instance of SQL Server.

Comment: No particular reason I guess other than the OP is currently using a local temp table. Updated my answer to clarify.